# Showing SWT modal dialog from AWT/Swing

Tags: swt, swt-awt, albireo

Using Albireo, it's easy to see how to show a Swing dialog from SWT:

```
private AwtEnvironment awtEnv = AwtEnvironment.getInstance(Display.getCurrent);

...
// call from SWT thread
void showSwingMessageDialog(String msg) {
    awtEnv.invokeAndBlockSwt(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Frame parentFrame = awtEnv.createDialogParentFrame();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(parentFrame, msg);
        }
    }
}
```

I want to show an SWT dialog from AWT thread, i.e.

```
// call from AWT thread
void showSWTMessageDialog(String msg) {
    ???
}
```

Comment: Can you please post more code than just a one line..?

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov Hey there, did you ever figure this out? Having the same problem, trying to make a new shell block a JFrame.

Comment: @milez Not that I remember, but I've been gone from that job and working with SWT for over 2 years now.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure, if I understand this question well, but when you are writing program with Albireo/SWT_AWT bridge, you use SWT normally and when you need, you can use Swing for some work (as [this example on eclipse wiki](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Albireo_Documentation#Standalone_SWT_application_development) shows).. So if you have your parent (most probably `Shell` instance) in some global attribute, you can just create SWT dialog whenever and wherever you need..

**EDIT**

For blocking the AWT thread, you could call [invokeAndWait()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeAndWait%28java.lang.Runnable%29) method of `SwingUtilities` and inside the `Runnable` instance show the SWT dialog window..

Comment: I'm not sure, you'll have to probably try that.. Anyway, why do you want to block the thread?
Maybe this small part of [wiki article](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Albireo_Documentation#Multiple_Event_Threads) will help you, or more deep (and longer) article [about SWT and AWT](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-Swing-SWT-Integration/index.html) will help to answer the question..

Comment: "Anyway, why do you want to block the thread?" The "Modal dialogs" section of the Eclipse Corner article explains why this is needed (but not how to do it).