# True application modal SWT shell from AWT JFrame

Tags: java, swing, shell, swt, awt

I have a Java Swing application and I'm embedding an SWT widget to it. I'm trying to display an SWT `Shell` from my AWT `JFrame` but cannot make it application modal. The `JFrame` can still be focused and button clicks will register to the EDT. What steps do I take to make the `Shell` behave like a modal AWT dialog?

I have read [this outdated tutorial](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-Swing-SWT-Integration/index.html) but it only explains how to do it if the application is running on the SWT event thread. I also tried to hack this with a modal `JDialog` but the behavior is ugly at best. Remove the comments from the minimum working example to demo it. `SWT.ON_TOP` is troublesome in itself, since ithe `shell` will stay on top of every window.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6763254/showing-swt-modal-dialog-from-awt-swing) did not help.

SSCE

```
public class ModalDialogExample extends JFrame {

public ModalDialogExample()
{
    this.setSize(500, 500);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    JFrame frame = new ModalDialogExample();
    JButton button = new JButton("CLick me");
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
//              JDialog modalDialog = new JDialog();
//              modalDialog.setSize(new Dimension(0,0));
//              modalDialog.setModalityType(ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);
            Display display = new Display();
            Shell shell = new Shell(display, SWT.CLOSE | SWT.TITLE | SWT.BORDER | SWT.OK | SWT.ON_TOP | SWT.APPLICATION_MODAL);
            shell.setSize(200,200);
            shell.open();
            shell.forceActive();
//              modalDialog.setVisible(true);
            while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
                if (!display.readAndDispatch())
                    display.sleep();
            }
            display.dispose();
        }
    });
    frame.getContentPane().add(button);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I came up with. It is not perfect but does the job. Recall I had a `JFrame` on top of which I needed a modal SWT `Shell` behaving like a modal `JDialog`.

1. The `Shell` that is started can not live in the AWT event dispatch thread. We need access to the thread to intercept mouse and window events later. So start the `Shell` in a new `Thread`
2. I placed a `GlassPane` on my `JFrame` for the time the `Shell` was open. The purpose was to block other interactive Swing components in the frame and it's containers and to intercept all mouse events. I needed the mouse events, so I could not simply do `Frame.setEnabled(false)`.
3. I used on `WindowListener` on the frame and a `MouseListener` on the `GlassPane`
4. I used a `DisposeListener` on the `Shell` to detect the moment when the `JFrame` has to lose the `GlassPane` and other modifications done for the time the `Shell` is live.
5. **To control the visibility of the `Shell` with my Swing listeners I needed access to the SWT event thread.** This is done by executing `Runnable` with `shell.getDisplay().syncExec(...)`

This is how I launch the `Shell`, activate the `GlassPane`, attach "modality listeners" and also remove them when the `Shell` is closed. The `Shell` is started in a new thread.

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {

            final Shell shell = myWidget.getShell();

            final EditorWindowListener ewl = new EditorWindowListener(shell);
            myFrame.addWindowListener(ewl);

            final EditorClickListener ecl = new EditorClickListener(shell);
            myFrame.getGlassPane().addMouseListener(ecl);

            myFrame.getGlassPane().setVisible(true);
            shell.addDisposeListener(new DisposeListener() {

            //Remove the disabled status
                @Override
                public void widgetDisposed(DisposeEvent arg0) {
                    myFrame.removeWindowListener(ewl);
                    myFrame.getGlassPane().removeMouseListener(ecl);
                    myFrame.getGlassPane().setVisible(false);
                }
            });
            //The method that starts the shell
            myWidget.show();
        }
}).start();
```

This is what happens in `myWidget.show()` (standard SWT stuff, no modifications)

```
shell.open();   
shell.forceActive();
while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
    if (!display.readAndDispatch())
        display.sleep();
}
display.dispose();
```

Here are the two listeners I add to the frame and glassPane. First the `MouseListener` that detects clicks on the glass pane and if any event is caught, brings the `Shell` to the top. I know this would not be needed in a perfectly modal dialog, and mostly it is not needed in this case either, but some dual monitor setups caused problems that were solved with this listener.

```
class EditorClickListener extends MouseAdapter
{
    private Shell shell;

    public EditorClickListener(Shell s)
    {
        this.shell = s;
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        shellToFront(shell);
    }
}
```

Then the `WindowListener` attached to the frame. It makes sure anytime the frame is active, the shell jumps on top.

```
class EditorWindowListener extends WindowAdapter
{
    Shell shell;
    public EditorWindowListener(Shell s)
    {
        this.shell = s;
    }

    @Override
    public void windowOpened(WindowEvent e) {
        shellToFront(shell);
    }

    @Override
    public void windowDeiconified(WindowEvent e) {
        shellToFront(shell);
    }

    @Override
    public void windowActivated(WindowEvent e) {
        //Set the shell on top of the frame
        //Fixes some problems with dual monitor setups.
        final java.awt.Point framePoint = myFrame.getLocation();
        shellToFront(shell);
        shell.getDisplay().syncExec(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                shell.setMinimized(false);
                shell.setActive();
                org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Point shellPoint = aikataulu.getLocation();
                shellPoint.x = (int) framePoint.getX();
                shellPoint.y = (int) framePoint.getY();
                shell.setLocation(shellPoint);
            }
        });     
    }
}
```

And finally the method to pop the shell to your face to create a feeling of modality. Note that all events need to assigned to happen in the SWT event thread. I had some trouble with setting the minimized state to `false`. So I had to add an artificial minimization in case the `Shell` was not minimized and was indeed behind other windows. This results in a stupid unnecessary animation in some use cases, but for now it will make do

```
private void shellToFront(final Shell shell)
{
    shell.getDisplay().syncExec(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (!shell.getMinimized())
            {
                shell.setMinimized(true);
            }
            shell.setMinimized(false);
            shell.setActive();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: If anyone can help me refine these methods, for example get rid of unnecessary minimization animations, I will award the bounty to that person.